# A Scheme procedure that returns the largest index used in a program L

Tags: programming-languages, scheme

Say I have a program defined:

```
(define myprog
  (a-program
   (list (labeled 'A12 (add1 'X)) (unlabeled (sub1 'Y4)))))
```

I want to write a procedure to find the largest index used in the above program.

A test case would be like:

```
>(max-index myprog);myprog is the program defined above
12 
;this is from A12 because its the largest index used.
```

I know that scheme has a built in function that finds the largest element in a list like
`(max 3 5 9)`
would give me 9

but in my case, I understand that I would have to parse my program and also consider omitted indices will correspond to 1; X corresponds to X1.

I can write a function that does this easily in lists but not a 'program'.

If someone could tell me what should I first look at, that'll be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"A Program" in the sense defined in your question *is* a list of lists, and nothing else. If you know how to write a function that does what you need for "a list" please post it here, you'll see that it works for "a program" too.